# Calling methods in Other forms C# Winforms

Tags: c#, database, winforms, linq, methods

I am making a POS system with a C# WinForms application and have a `Form1` (main screen) and a `Checkout` screen (can be thought of as Form2). There is a method in `Form1` called `clearSale()`. I am trying to call it through this button event in `Form2`:

```
private void btnProccessComplete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Order Successfully Processed for: $" + checkoutTotal.ToString("F2"), "Successful Payment", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    readyStock(checkoutItems);
    isCheckoutComplete = true;
    Form1 myObj = new Form1();
    myObj.clearSale();
    this.Close();
}
```

In result of this event finishing it calls the `clearSale()` method from `Form1`:

```
public void clearSale()
{
    itemList.Items.Clear();
    txtUPCScan.Clear();
    orderTotal = 0.00;
    lblTotalPrice.Text = "$0.00";
    picPay.Enabled = false;
    myShoppingCartItems = null;
    myShoppingCartItems = new string[250];
    totalItems = 0;
}
```

The `clearSale()` method pretty much just sets all the txtboxes back to an empty state and makes everything look brand new again. My issue is whenever the `clearSale()` method gets called in `Form1` it will work, but when it is called in `Form2` (like I'm trying to get it to) nothing changes on my main page. Like the method almost wasn't called. Everything stays the same and doesn't get cleared. Any help?

Comment: You are instantiating a new `Form1` and not using the instance of `Form1` that is being displayed

Comment: Google your question title. You'll find hundreds of same question with answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a new `Form1` object it will not reference the previously created ones. 
Pass `Form1` by a constructor parameter to `Form2`.

```
public class Form2: Form{

    Form1 mainObj;

    public Form2(Form1 _mainObj){
        this.mainObj = _mainObj;
    }

    private void btnProccessComplete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Order Successfully Processed for: $" + checkoutTotal.ToString("F2"), "Successful Payment", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        readyStock(checkoutItems);
        isCheckoutComplete = true;
        this.mainObj.clearSale();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

From `Form1` you now have to create `Form2` with:

```
Form2 checkout = new Form2(this);
```